# Balanced 2-d tree implementation in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

I wanted to ask for an advice on implementing a 2-d tree structure holding points in a balanced fasion.

What I have (an example): {0, 2}, {2, 3}, {5, 3}, {6, 4}

What I need (if I'm correct about balanced tree):

```
     {5, 3}
       |
{6, 4} - {2, 3}
           |
    {0, 2} - null
```

First I would like to know if my expeced outcome is correct taking in account the splitting dimension for *root* node is 0.

Then I'd like to share my algorithm and hear if it's a correct way to implement it:

1. Pass list of points to root object
2. Find median point and assign it to root "point"
3. Split list of points using the median point
4. Create two child objects "left" and "right" with swapped splitting dimension
5. Pass lists of points to two child objects
6. Go to point 2 for child objects (now becoming *root* objects for the purpose of this algorith)

Is that a correct way? Should I use another way? I was searching for any samples, but I only found n dimensional implementations similar to that:

https://code.google.com/p/kd-sharp/source/browse/trunk/KDTree/KDNode.cs

Which seems overly complicated for my purpose.

Comment: I think this question would be better asked on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange site.  Questions like this that ask for opinions are considered inappropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you post this question to Code Review, please be aware that the code under review must be included *directly in the question*  on Code Review. Aside from that this question may warrant some cleanup edits, but seems to be okay for [codereview.se]

Comment: well, I wasn't sure of that because I don't really have any code :) that's why I've chosen SO. Should I really post the question to Code Review instead?

Comment: Your algorithm descriptions sounds reasonable. But your example looks odd. Why is `{6, 4}` left of `{5, 3}`. On the first dimension, it is greater, thus it should be in the right sub tree.

Comment: @user1970395 No, code review is for review of working *code* (what's in a name). Many questions that would be off-topic on SO in general are on-topic with the algorithms tag, so this one seems fine here to me.

Comment: @NicoSchertler you're absolutely right, of course, I didn't pay much attention to left-right, but yes, it should be another way around. I've also implemented it and it gives a reasonable performance (3,5s for 500,000 points) and could go even more I believe with some opitmalization.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is exactly a KD-tree in 2 dimensions.

I would just use the library if nothing else prevents you from doing it.